# Replacing embedded apostrophes, but only certain ones

Tags: c#, regex, escaping

Given an arbitrary string of this form

" and x = 'o'reilly' and y = 'o'reilly' and z = 'abc' "

can anyone suggest a straight forward way of substituting '' for the ' characters embedded in the o'reilly parts? (It may of course be any sequence with an embedded apostrophe).

I have no control over the general pattern of the string. It could be anything containing parts of the form 'zzz'bbb', and maybe even 'aaa'bbb'ccc' where the inner apostrophes need to be replaced, but not the "outer" apostrophes.

I've tried regular expressions, and all the rest. I'm stumped, but I gotta solve it!

TIA.

Comment: what's "iv'e tried this and all the rest" ?

Comment: It's obvious that unless you are willing to make certain assumptions there will always be several ways to interpret the same input in the general case. So the question is not really answerable without such assumptions (i.e. if the most accurate specification you can give is "certain ones"). Also, I **really** hope it is not SQL you are trying to "fix" in this manner.

Comment: It's not SQL per se, but the string could end up being used as a SQL query later down the line.

Comment: Well four people have understood what I am asking, and have given helpful answers so I don't underdstand why this is unclear. "can anyone suggest a straight forward way of substituting '' for the ' characters embedded in the o'reilly parts? (It may of course be any sequence with an embedded apostrophe)" seems clear to me (and to them too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example for you:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = "and x = 'o'reilly' and y = 'o'reilly' and z = 'abc' ";
        var output = input
            .Select((c, i) => new { Character = c, Index = i })
            .Where(o =>
            {
                if (o.Character != Convert.ToChar("'")) { return false; }

                var i = o.Index;
                var charBefore = (i == 0) ? false :
                    char.IsLetter(input[i - 1]);
                var charAfter = (i == input.Length - 1) ? false :
                    char.IsLetter(input[i + 1]);

                return charBefore && charAfter;
            })
            .ToList();

        foreach (var item in output)
        {
            input = input.Remove(item.Index, 1);
            input = input.Insert(item.Index, "\"");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(input);
        if (Debugger.IsAttached) { Console.ReadKey(); }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
and x = 'o"reilly' and y = 'o"reilly' and z = 'abc'
```

Basically, all it does, is get a listing of anonymous objects that give an index for every character, filters that to just `'` that are prefixed and suffixed by a letter, and then modified the input by index off the results of those objects.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I have to use .Net 3.5 - no named parameters (ie I cannot do new { Character = c, Index = i } ). But it gives food for thought.

Comment: @haughtonomous, it would still work if you just created a class for it. Create a new class named `SplitString` or something, add the values to the constructor, and do `new SplitString(c, i)`.

Comment: Thanks - I realised that, but I thought I ought to mention the linmitations of my .Net version. I have a class in my toolbox (Tuple<T,T>) which would fit the bill nicely.

Comment: With a couple of judicious changes (eg I need a double apostrophe instead of a double quote character), your suggestion works very nicely. Thanks!

Comment: @haughtonomous, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to assume that the embedded apostrophes always occur with a alphanumeric character on both sides (and not a space), then you could do simply this:

```
(\w)'(\w)
```

and then do a replace with:

```
\1\2
```

That will have the effect of removing apostrophes between alphanumerics. Take a look at this RegExr: http://regexr.com?376k9

Example:

```
'hello there i am a representative from 'o'reilly' publishing and i am '2'3' years old'
```

becomes:

```
'hello there i am a representative from 'oreilly' publishing and i am '23' years old'
```

Comment: Ah - I can't simply remove the "embedded" apostrophes. I can "escape" them, but not remove them.

Comment: Oh okay, well then you could just as simply do `\1"\2`, which will replace the single apostrophe with a double quote. If you're looking to replace the apostrophe with a fixed character (or string of characters), you can just put the character(s) in between the `\1` and `\2`

Comment: I managed to do it by simple string manipulation in the end, but thanks to all for ideas and suggestions, which helped me find my solution.

Comment: But can you be a little more explicit about how you would do it with a regex? I'm not quite sure I get what you are saying.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know a dang thing about C#, but most languages have a string replacement method that allow you to replace a regular expression in a string with another string. Take a peek at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Just skimming from the MSDN docs, you could create a new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex object with the constructor argument `(\w)'(\w)`, then use its method `Replace` like this:

`myRegex = new Regex((\w)'(\w))`
`myRegex.Replace(myString, $1"$2)`

That will replace the apos. between the two letters with a quote

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'd probably go with a regex on this one ... since all you really need is to find the apostrophe where the letter before and after are not white spaces ... should be quite easy.

Otherwise, you could just run a string.indexof("'") , check that the position before and after are not white space ... and BOOM ...blow it out of the water ...

```
string test = "aoeu'aou ";
string bad_test = "aoeu ' aoeu";

var index = test.IndexOf("'");
if (!test[index-1].Equals(' ') && !test[index+1].Equals(' '))
Console.Out.WriteLine("Boom at index "+ index);
else
Console.Out.WriteLine("seems we have some spaces");

index = bad_test.IndexOf("'");
if (! bad_test[index - 1].Equals(' ') && !bad_test[index + 1].Equals(' '))
Console.Out.WriteLine("Boom at index " + index);
else
Console.Out.WriteLine("seems we have some spaces");
```

this will output:

> Boom at index 4
>   seems we have some spaces

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for sth like this?

```
    var splittedString = " and x = 'o'reilly' and y = 'o'reilly' and z = 'abc' ".Split(new char[] {' '},
                                                                                       StringSplitOptions
                                                                                           .RemoveEmptyEntries);
    List<string> listStrings = splittedString.Select(s => s.Trim('\'').Replace('\'', '"')).ToList();
    var finalResult = "";

    var prevMatchIsEqualToSign = false;
    foreach (var s in listStrings)
    {
        if (prevMatchIsEqualToSign)
        {
            finalResult += "'" + s + "' ";
        }
        else if (s == "=")
        {
            finalResult += "= ";
            prevMatchIsEqualToSign = true;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            finalResult += s +" ";
        }
        prevMatchIsEqualToSign = false;

    }
    Console.WriteLine(finalResult);
```